# How can I hide parts of an object that don't overlap another object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask

What is the best way to remove the part of the blue object that doesn't overlap the grey object?

[image]

Comment: Hi DesignerGraphic, your question is a little confusing. Can you please be more specific in what you're trying to do and let us know what you have tried? There are numerous ways you can manipulate how an object is shown, ex: clipping mask, layer hierarchy, path finder options etc.

Comment: Is the blue "object" a stroke or is that expanded?

Comment: Blue "object" is a stroke and I want to have it only on gray object. I want that bottom blue to be deleted (because it's outside of gray object)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a clipping mask.

1. Select your grey object.
2. Copy it (<kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or `Edit > Copy`).
3. Paste it in front (`Edit > Paste in Front` or <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>).
4. Arrange the copy so it is on top of the blue object. Use the layers palette or the arrange shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> for this.
5. Remove all appearance from the grey object: stroke, fill and effects.
6. Select both the no-stroke-no-fill object and the blue object.
7. Make a clipping mask: `Object > Clipping Mask > Make`.

The mask is a 'clipping group' you can edit to change either the clipping path or the masked object. You can enter the group in the `Layers` palette or with <kbd>double click</kbd> to enter isolation mode.